# Google Maps API How to disable smooth transition?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In Google Maps API when I'm using the map.setCenter method and my origin and destination points are both in the viewport, then the setCenter method works like panTo method with smooth transition to the destination. Can I disable smooth transitions for setCenter method?